# Analog input scaling before ADC sampling

Tags: microcontroller, operational-amplifier, analog, adc

I'm trying to read a voltage value from a chemical sensor. the sensor value can range from 0 to 7 volts. My microcontroller is running on 3.3V. I'm not allowed to consume current from the sensor so I used the following circuit to amplify the current.
[image]

But this circuit is not acting like what I've learned in theory.

1. When the input terminal is left unconnected the output voltage is about 3V.
2. When the input voltage is below 0.8V the output is also 3V but when the input voltage goes higher than 0.8V the input falls to 0.300V.
3. The transfer function of the input to output is not linear!

What is the best practice to solve this problem?

Comment: is it possible that you swapped inverting and non-inverting inputs?

Comment: Yes, I double checked.

Answer (score 4):

Well, the schematic in principle is correct, and from theory it should work. HOWEVER you didn't check your common mode ranges (both input and output ones).

The TL JFET amplifiers are quite old (still good, however) and designed for dual power supply (typically ±15V, they work with less but *not* with ±5V).

From the datasheet you'll see that it's input CM range, when powered at ±15V is guaranteed to be only ±11V. So, approximately, if you power it at 12V single supply, you CM range will be 4 to 8V. Clearly you signal in the range 0 to 4V cannot per processed properly.

In the same way, the guaranteed output swing would be ±12V which translates to 3V to 9V. *Most* of your useful signal range is now out of the guaranteed linear zone of the amplifier.

Luckily you only need to use another opamp and they almost have the same identical pinout. Look for a single supply amp that can go down to 0V both in input and output. For a popular part the LM358 when powered from 12V should fit the bill (unless you *really* need to go lower than about 5mV, then you need another amp *and* begin worrying about offset)

EDIT: I read that you had issues with LM358 too. And are using a chemical sensor.

Well, these things tend have horrible output impedances, they get loaded just looking at them. Probably they suggested you the TL since it has a huge input impedance. First of all, check if you circuit is linear giving it a good input signal (from a power supply, from example). Once this is fine is time to attack the sensor itself.

You could try with another FET input amplifier, a CMOS amplifier, an instrumentation amplifier and as last resort, they made special amplifiers just for electrochemical sensors. Well, the last resort is actually a custom designed discrete amplifier…

It could help know the kind of sensor, they have wildly different requirements: some need only a huge input impedance, some have biasing current issues. Often there is a reference schematic to get you started in the sensor manual.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I found CA3130EZ op-amp with an input resistance of 1.5TOhms. Could it be a good choice?

Comment: they *still* make that part? it fits the bill, however you'll find better and maybe cheaper alternatives (unless you really need the DIP package)

Comment: I really appreciate it if you let me know about the alternatives you are speaking about.

Answer (score 3):

The TL072 is not a single supply OpAmp. When you choose GND as negative supply, you have to keep your input voltage at 2V or higher to stay within spec. When you are out of spec, unforeseen things can happen.

For your application it would be best to supply the OpAmp with a symmetric supply of +/-9V or +/-12V or so.

---

The choice of alternative OpAmps depends on the required minimum output voltage. Even single supply OpAmps can not go down to exactly 0V at the output. An example would be the LT1013 for something between 1$ and 2$. It can go down to about 15mV at the output. If this is low enough for you, this would be a nice and stable choice.
An OP113 is more like 4$ to 5$, but can go as low as 100µV at the output.

But as already mentioned, the best choice for your application will be to use a symmetrical supply voltage. The TL072 is a great OpAmp and by using +/-12V you won't have problems with non-linearity around ground.

Comment: Oh damn, I thought it is a single supply op-amp. Do you have any good substitutes which I can replace in my circuit?

Comment: I expanded my answer by some suggestions for alternative OpAmps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can easily supply CA3130EZ  could it be a good choice?

Comment: Yes, I see nothing that would speak against that one. It can go down on the output to 10mV.

Comment: I can use it in single supply also?

Comment: Yes, you can. Check out the datasheet, it tells you everything you need to know ;)

Comment: Thank you jusaca. I'm reading it but I'm not good at understanding datasheets so I asked to be sure about it. Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 3):

1. Undefined input voltage causes undefined output voltage. This is normal. Even a megaohm resistor from input to ground would fix it, if you are allowed to do that.
2. TL072 has 0V negative supply and it is not a rail-to-rail opamp. So it does not work when input and/or output voltages are lower than around 3V, so this is normal. You need a different op-amp or about -5V for the negative supply.
3. The circuit has problems working so it might be the op-amp circuit that is not linear. Or the ADC input requires lower impedance.

Comment: Before using TL072 I used LM358 instead, but with lm358 I also had the non-linearity problem, someone suggested me to change lm358 with TL072 but I think he was not aware that my circuit is single supply. So you think the circuit looks fine I have to find a good op-amp for it to run correctly?

Comment: No, if you need it to go down to 0V. Not even rail to rail opamps to exactly 0V, it will be within few millivolts but not 0V.