# Op-amp voltage follower not working as expected

Tags: microcontroller, operational-amplifier, adc

I previously asked about a [circuit to scale my analog value](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/548794/analog-input-scaling-before-adc-sampling/548802?noredirect=1#comment1430285_548802) before MCU ADC.

Based on the answers I got from that post I decided to change my op-amp from a TL072 to a CA3130.

The following pictures show my circuit schematic and PCB.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I just tried the circuit and it is not working as I expected it to.

When the input is left unconnected the op-amp output is about 8V. When I connect a voltage source of 1V to input the output voltage of op-amp is 7V. For a 6V input, the op-amp output is 9.6.

I couldn't figure out how it is working. When I read about a voltage-follower circuit I thought how easy it is, but in practice, I learned it is not that easy.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [CA3130 op-amp](https://www.renesas.com/eu/en/document/dst/ca3130-ca3130a-datasheet) needs "compensation" because it is not unity gain stable. You need to connect a capacitor between pins 1 and 8 (circa 47 pF) to ensure the op-amp doesn't turn into an oscillator in unity gain situations: -

[image]

What this picture tells you is that the open-loop gain is still something like 31 dB by the time the phase angle shift on the output has changed by 180 degrees. At this point, the CA3130 turns into an oscillator and all bets are off. Of course, if you find that a little difficult the data sheet is more explicit: -

[image]

Of course, you could just swap them out with the CA3140 - these are designed to be unity gain stable because they use an internal compensation capacitor: -

[image]

It's also good practice to put 100 nF decoupling capacitors across the op-amp power supply pins close to those pins (12 volts and 0 volts). Call it a safeguard against "strange" power delivery impedance problems outside of your control.

Comment: Thank you very much Andy. I replaced the CA3130 with CA3140 and it is perfect!

Answer (score 7):

Checking the usual suspects in the opamp datasheet:

> The use of PMOS transistors in the input stage
> results in common-mode input-voltage capability down to
> 0.5V below the negative-supply terminal, an important
> attribute in single-supply applications.

OK, input common mode range includes ground which is what you want.

Note on page 2, input common mode range only goes to 3V (typical) 5V (worst case) below VCC, so with 12V supply you will get 0...7V worst case, 0...9V typical on the output. Should be fine

> A CMOS transistor-pair, capable of swinging the output
> voltage to within 10mV of either supply-voltage terminal (at
> very high values of load impedance), is employed as the
> output circuit.

Output is close to rail-to-rail, which is also good if you want to measure down to OV.

> When the input is left unconnected the op-amp output is about 8V.

If the input is unconnected, the tiny leakage current through the input FET will be enough to generate a fake voltage at the input of the opamp. The usual solution is to connect a resistor to ground at the input, but since you say in your other question that you need a very high impedance input to not draw any current from your chemical sensor, you could just leave the sensor connected to the input. Please consider adding a filter capacitor to ground on the input though, something like 100pF C0G ceramic, that will short out EMI noise picked up by the sensor. Without this cap, when the cables pick up electromagnetic radiation from, for example, a nearby cellphone, you could get bogus readings.

> When I read about a voltage-follower circuit I thought how easy it is, but in practice, I learned it is not that easy!

Well, to be honest, you were a bit unlucky...

For a voltage follower (unity gain) you need an opamp that is "unity gain stable" and this one is not. Check out page 5:

> A 47pF capacitor provides sufficient compensation for stable unity-gain operation in most applications.

So the opamp is probably oscillating. Pick a C0G ceramic cap, or film cap, or just use an opamp that is unity gain stable.

Note this opamp is pretty fast at 15 MHz gain bandwidth, so it will require a supply decoupling cap. Something like 100nF - 1µF ceramic between power supply and ground. One cap should be enough for the three opamps. You can drill a hole on top of the middle opamp and put the cap between the power trace and the ground plane.

Comment: Thank you very much bobflux. Your answer was very informative. sorry I had to choose one answer as the correct answer both your and andy's answers was correct and helpful.